# Prove $f(n) = 3n^2+10n$ is in $\Theta(n^2)$

Tags: asymptotics, proof-writing

I've proven it's in $O(n^2)$ by having $n = 1$ and $c > 13$ (namely $c = 14$). How do I prove it for big theta?

Answer (score 4):

The inequality in the other direction is easier, since $n^2\lt 3n^2 +10n$ if $n\ge 1$.